# Linq Query, messed up where clause in method

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, windows-phone-7, linq-to-entities

I have a query that should return a sum of total hours reported for the current week.
This code below returns the Correct total of hours but not for a specific user in the database.

```
    public int reportedWeekTime(int currentWeek, string username)
        {
            var totalTime = (from u in context.Users
                         from r in context.Reports
                         from w in context.Weeks
                         from d in context.Days
                         where u.Id == r.UserId && r.weekNr.Equals(currentWeek) && r.Id   == w.ReportId && w.DayId == d.Id
                         select d.Hour).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum();
            return totalTime;
        }
```

The first method returns the number 24, wich is correct but as  i said, not for a specific user.

I am trying to do this, but it gives me 0 in return. What am i doing wrong?

```
    public int reportedWeekTime(int currentWeek, string username)
        {
            var totalTime = (from u in context.Users
                         from r in context.Reports
                         from w in context.Weeks
                         from d in context.Days
                         where u.Id == r.UserId && r.weekNr.Equals(currentWeek) && r.Id == w.ReportId && w.DayId == d.Id && u.Username.Contains(username)
                         select d.Hour).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum();
            return totalTime;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you should set the username to a property in your class. I know WP7 Linq isn't that good with passed in values of a method

Comment: you need to use join http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9

Comment: Passing the username to the method like this works for another linq query i use, but not for this specific one.

Comment: Well, none of context.Users contains "username". You should try to display the result of this query to understand what's giong on: `context.Users.Where(user => !user.Contains(username))`

Comment: A join gives me same result. KooKiz: context.Users.Where(user => !user. does not have property contains. But context.users.where(user => user.username.Contains(username)) also gives result 0.

Comment: So your problem isn't your linq query, your problem is just that you have no username meeting the criteria. Note that the `Contains` method is case sensitive.

Comment: The user with the specific username is in the database. But the linq query still returns null or 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** - Troubleshooting approach, create a new anonymous class with the u.Username property, the string username, and the comparison. It will be easier to visualize what is going on

```
var users = (from u in context.Users
             select new
             { 
               UsernameDb = u.Username,
               UsernameSearch = username,
               Comparison = u.Username.Contains(username),
             }).ToList();
```

**Original**

I would modify your query slightly:

1. Use `join`'s instead of `from`'s with `where` clauses
2. Remove the `DefaultIfEmpty(0)`

(1) Is more for readability, but I think (2) is the cause of your problem

```
var totalTime = (from u in context.Users
                 join r in context.Reports on u.Id equals r.UserId
                 join w in context.Weeks on r.Id equals w.ReportId
                 join d in context.Days on w.DayId equals d.Id
                 where r.weekNr.Equals(currentWeek) && u.Username.Contains(username)
                 select d.Hour).Sum();
```

I would also make sure that the following query returns result. If not, than that would be your problem

```
var users = from u in context.Users
            where u.Username.Contains(username)
            select u;
```

Comment: i would love to try this, but the select statement gives me errorcode " Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int' "

Comment: @rickard - Ok, I assumed d.Hour was nullable. Have you tried removing the DefaultIfEmpty(0)? Why did you add that?

Comment: I had DefaultIfEmpty if a person have added a reports but have no hours addes to it. That would return the value 0. But the problem is still here, i know it should return me a value, but it does not. It instead gives me "The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."

Comment: @rickard - I understand now. **u.Username.contains(username)** is not returning any results.

Comment: i think you have located the problem. How can i solve it ? :) I Cant compare the username in database with the username from my method. They are both strings but of a different type?

Comment: @rickard - I updated my answer with a troubleshooting approach that I think will help you visualize your problem

Comment: from nowhere the solution is now working. I marked your answear as the correct one. I just added DefaultIfEmpty(0) again to make sure if no value is set, method will return 0. Thanks for the help